# Kendo dropdown list popup height not working

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

In this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qoygtz?file=app/app.component.ts) I have a Kendo for Angular dropdown list with a popup height set to 20px. Still, when I open the dropdown list the popup height remains unchanged. How to make this work?

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
 <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="listItems" [popupSettings]="{ height: 20 }">
 </kendo-dropdownlist>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
  public listItems: Array<string> = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better way to do that is to use popupClass instead of height. That enables you to define a css class that is executed for the popup. In that class you can define attributes like min-height etc.

```
[popupSettings]="{ popupClass: 'myPopupClass' }"
```

[See documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/PopupSettings/)

**Edit**:

In the above solution it looks like you have to set ViewEncapsulation.None and set the height property in the css.

I found an easier solution:

Looks like you also have to set the '[listHeight](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/DropDownListComponent/#toc-listheight)'. By default the listHeight is 200px.

Look at this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qoygtz-eyp71y)

```
<kendo-dropdownlist [data]="listItems" [popupSettings]="{ height: 20 }" listHeight="20">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I cannot set the height dynamically. Also, I see `height` in the documentation, why is it not working?

Comment: By the way, look at [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qoygtz-fj6gyg), it's not working either.

Comment: Thanks for the update, now it worked, but I had to use `[listHeight]` not sure why.

Comment: You have to use [ ] in case of binding to a variable i.e. [listHeight]="variablename" vs. listheight="20"